# Gremlin selective traversal

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

This might be a rookie Gremlin question :

Let's say I have this graph

A [knows---> ] B

A [knows---> ] C

D [knows---> ] C

I want to traverse this graph and find nodes whom only A knows , in this case B and not C because both A and D know C. Is there a way to do this with Gremlin ?

Edit : 
Sorry I should have been more explicit in the question initially
The number of incoming edges can actually be variable.

```
g.addV('A').as('a')
  .addV('B').as('b')
  .addV('C').as('c')
  .addV('D').as('d')
  .addV('E').as('e')
  .addV('F')as('f')
  .addE('knows').from('a').to('c')
  .addE('knows').from('b').to('c')
  .addE('knows').from('a').to('f')
  .addE('knows').from('b').to('f')
  .addE('knows').from('d').to('f')
```

In this case I want only C and not F because A & B know C and F both but D also knows F so I don't want F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful to have a small sample graph. Here is one that matches your question.

```
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addV('D').as('d').
  addE('knows').from('a').to('b').
  addE('knows').from('a').to('c').
  addE('knows').from('d').to('c')
```

Using that graph the query to find friends unique to A could be written as

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').
               out('knows').
               filter(__.in('knows').count().is(1)).
               path().
               by(label)  

==>[A,B]
```

Edited based on the updated question.

OK so given the additional criteria, I believe this gives you what you need

```
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('A','B').
......1>        out().
......2>        groupCount().
......3>        unfold().
......4>        filter(select(values).is(2)).
......5>        select(keys).
......6>        where(__.in('knows').count().is(2)).
......7>        label()  

==>C
```

Comment: Thanks @KevinLawrence. Sorry I should have been more explicit in the question. The number of incoming edges can actually be variable.So it can be `g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addV('D').as('d').addV('E').as('e').addV('F')as('f')
.addE('knows').from(a).to(c).addE('knows').from(b).to(c).addE('knows').from(a).to(f).addE('knows').from(b).to(f).addE('knows').from(d).to(f).` In this case I want only C returned if I start with hasLabel('A')&hasLabel('B').out('knows').Basically both A and B know C. A and B also know F but D knows F as well so I don't want F.

Comment: Could you please clarify the exact results you are looking for. I am not clear on what the criteria are to keep or rule out a person. Your question still states find people only A knows which the query I put in the answer will do.

Comment: The criteria is to start with A and B see whom they know mutually and exclusively.
Basically I want to pick a node that has the "knows" relationship exclusively from the starting nodes that I started traversing the graph with and no one else.

To Define it : Find Person A and B mutually know but no one else knows that person (so in above case C) . Also updated the question so it's easier to read.